# Spark Scala Convert Big RDD to Dataframe performance issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I have a  `RDD` output (22 columns, 10000 rows) of a spark Hbase connector and I have to convert it to a `DataFrame`.

Here is my method :

```
val DATAFRAME = hBaseRDD.map(x => {
(Bytes.toString(x._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("header"), Bytes.toBytes("Id"))),
Bytes.toString(x._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("header"), Bytes.toBytes("Time"))),
...
Bytes.toString(x._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("measures"), Bytes.toBytes("measure_i"))))})
.toDF()
.withColumnRenamed("_1", "Time")
.withColumnRenamed("_2", "name example 2")
... 
.withColumnRenamed("_i", "name example i")
.sort("Time")
```

It works well, the problem is the performance, is there any way to optimize it ?

Thk's in advance

Comment: You can use hortonworks shc connector to load hbase table directly into dataframe, it can give you some performance boost. check out https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc